# Add a day to a date in Postgres and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2017

I'm looking to find a way to add a day to a date in both Postgres and SQL Server so I don't have to add an if condition checking which database the server is running

```
DATEADD(day, 1, STOP_DATE)
```

doesn't work in PostgreSQL &

```
STOP_DATE + 1
```

doesnt work in sql server

Comment: Every dialect of SQL is different, you shouldn't be expecting SQL that is written for one RDBMS to work for another. There are very few times when they *do*, normally with very simple syntax. Even ANSI-SQL isn't always transferable, as different RDBMS don't support all parts of it; and often not the same parts.

Comment: Seriously, it's not worth it given the amount of differences between SQL Server and Postgres

Comment: Hi Larnu and Charlieface, unfortunately this is the way it is for our codebase. I was hoping there might be a common ground for this specific action as we encounter it relatively frequent

Comment: Side note, the syntax you have for the second query *would* work for the older date and time data types. I (and many others) really dislike the `{date value} + {numerical value}` syntax; a date (and time) isn't a numerical value after all, so adding a number to it doesn't make sense. [According to by GoogleFu](https://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd), the equivalent of `DATEADD` in PostgreSQL for `DATEADD` expression you have would actually be `STOP_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day'`.

Comment: Like we both said, write bespoke SQL for the RDBMS you are using, @Laurens . If you have multiple environments, with different RDBMS, then you'll need to use settings within the application to ensure you use the correct SQL statement.

Comment: @Larnu: note that Postgres only allows `date_value + integer` it does not allow adding arbitrary "numeric values". As the smallest unit for a `date` is a day, there is also no ambiguity on what `date_value + 1` actually means.

Comment: So are you saying here that PostgreSQL doesn't support Date and time values, or that or doesn't support `{date and time value} + {numerical value}` as a valid expression, @a_horse_with_no_name ? If the latter, then my point actually stands, as that means the syntax for adding to dates is different to date and times; and why the syntax I found appears to be explicitly better.

Comment: @Larnu: it only allows `date` (only) `+ integer`. For timestamp values (=date **and** time) Postgres only allows to add intervals (because it's impossible to implicitly derive the unit of the added value) . Adding an interval to a `date` yields a `timestamp` while adding an `integer` to a date yields a `date` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a95bfc1577c2d3396b4c4fd10cccb3a7

Comment: So adding a day to a date in PostgreSQL results in a date and time data type? That feels... Wrong, @a_horse_with_no_name, I must say.

Comment: Adding an **interval** to a date yields a timestamp (which is mandated by the SQL standard). You surely expect that adding "one day, five hours and six minutes" to a date yields a timestamp, would you not?

Comment: I don't expect adding a single **day** to a date to to make it a date and time, no @a_horse_with_no_name .

Comment: yes, but the type of `date + interval` has to always be the same. You and I @Lamu know that it's sensible to simplify things when adding whole days, but the type rules aren't so subtle.

Comment: You should create your own custom function AddDay, that will be implemented differently in Postgre or SQL Server, but allows you to use the same SQL on both.

Comment: L a r n u @RichardHuxton . Misspelling my alias won't ping me, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Larnu: well, as I wrote: the SQL standard mandates that adding an `interval` to a `date` results in a  `timestamp` - the length of the interval is irrelevant.

Comment: Doesn't mean I have to agree with it, @a_horse_with_no_name . Implicitly changing the data type of a value, when no other data types are involved, is not a *good* behaviour in my opinion. It would be like getting a `decimal` value when performing division with `int` values because it *might* need decimal places.

Comment: @Larnu: shrug. It's the same as `integer * decimal` yields decimal

Comment: There are 2 different data types involved there, @a_horse_with_no_name , so that makes sense.

Comment: `date` and `interval` are also two different data types.

Answer (score 3):

Overall, it is not a good idea to try to write SQL code using syntax that is common on both SQL Server and Postgres. You are severely limiting yourself and will sooner or later come across a query that runs too slowly because it doesn't use syntax specific to one of the DBMS.

For example, with your approach you are artificially refusing to use lateral joins, because their syntax is different in Postgres (`LATERAL JOIN`) and SQL Server (`CROSS/OUTER APPLY`).

---

Back to your question.

You can add an integer value to a `date` value in Postgres and to `datetime` value in SQL Server.

**SQL Server**

```
CREATE TABLE T(d datetime);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2020-01-01');

SELECT
  d, d+1 AS NextDay
FROM T
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d519d9/1

This will **not** work with `date` or `datetime2` data types in SQL Server, only `datetime`.

**Postgres**

```
CREATE TABLE T(d date);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2020-01-01');

SELECT
  d, d+1 AS NextDay
FROM T
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b9670/2

I don't know if it will work with other data types.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function in PostgreSQL that works like the sql server function.

Edit:

> can't pass day

Create a function with the same name on each database system that adds a day accordingly.

Comment: Not possible, because you can't pass `day` as a parameter. Only `'day'` (a string)

Comment: Then make 2 functions, one on each database system